# I'm looking for a specific cartoon TV show from 00s about kids possibly living in a...quite big house?

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

What I remember from this show is there were a bunch of human kids and a biiiiig house, and there were also monsters/creatures of some sort. I remember the color palette from my mental image is reddish-blackish, so darker colors. From what I remember it was a kinda dark kids show.

Other info I can give you: It was potentially on Nickelodeon or Cartoon Network, or maybe Fox Kids/Jetix or Discovery Kids, because those were the channels I had at the time. It could be an older cartoon that was shown in the early 00s, but it looked newer than most of those.

Things I've discarded so far have been Creepie, Aaahh!!! Real Monsters (too old and...realistic), Foster's Home for Imaginary Friends (too recent as well), Invader Zim...

If it wasn't for my sister also recalling the show I'd think I was imagining it. I also remember I found the intro or a video from that show a few years ago looking for cartoon intros and then...forgot the name again. Oh well. If any of you can figure this one out, you deserve a Nobel Prize.

EDIT: I'm now remembering two things that could help. 1, it could have just been a school and not a house, and the reason it was dark was it was an attic. Not sure why I only remember the one scene. The kids kinda looked...gothy, as well?
And 2, I believe the whole reason behind there being monsters and stuff there is they were solving mysteries.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe any of the monsters?

Comment: I really wish I could hahaha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know no time at all was spent, but I decided to look up "goth style cartoon shows" online and I found the show!

The show was "Creepschool"!

Seems like it's a very niche show so chances of finding it might have been tricky, but it's back in my brain after so long!

Here's the intro, if you have no clue what show it is:

And yes, it was on Nickelodeon where I live around like, 2005-2006.

Comment: Thats brilliant, good self-answer. Don't forget, in a few hours you'll be able to check the green tick, to accept this answer, and mark it as correct

Answer (score 2):

This may be a long shot but could it be Ruby Gloom? It ran from 2006-2008 featured a dark/gothic styling and is about a group of kids/monsters in a mansions/school. Each episode as I recall featured something for them to solve. The color palette is fairly dark though I don't recall general themes being too dark as it was still aimed at children.

This show jumped to mind reading the description and I found the name again by searching "ytv shows" after some failed targeted searches. ytv being the channel I saw the show on. It was on the third set of preview results google served to show the thumbnails and names.

Intro of the show:

Comment: Huh...it does look like it could be this. Apparently this show in Latin America was on a channel that I can't recall ever having, but maybe we had it somewhere along the lines.
I'll see if I can find something else from this show that can set off the alarm bells. Thanks!!